# Python subprocess get child's output

Tags: python, multithreading, subprocess, parent

> **Possible Duplicates:**
>   [How to get output from subprocess.Popen()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388753/how-to-get-output-from-subprocess-popen)
>   [Retrieving the output of subprocess.call()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1996518/retrieving-the-output-of-subprocess-call)

Here is my question. I have an executable called device_console. The device_console provides a command line interface to a device. In device_console, four commands can be run: status, list, clear and exit. Each command produces an output. As an example:

```
[asdfgf@localhost ~]$ device_console

device_console> list

File A

File B

device_console> status
Status: OK

device_console> clear
All files cleared

device_console> list
device_console> exit

[asdfgf@localhost ~]$
```

As part of testing, I want to get the output of each command. I want to use Python for it. I am looking at Python's subprocess, but somehow I am unable to put them together. Can you please help?

Comment: Duplicate of all of these: http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+subprocess+output.  Specifically, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388753/how-to-get-output-from-subprocess-popen as just one of many exact duplicates.

Answer (score 2):

it sounds like you want something more like 'Expect'.

check out [Pexpect](http://www.noah.org/wiki/Pexpect)

> "Pexpect is a pure Python module that
>   makes Python a better tool for
>   controlling and automating other
>   programs. Pexpect is similar to the
>   Don Libes `Expect` system, but Pexpect
>   as a different interface that is
>   easier to understand. Pexpect is
>   basically a pattern matching system.
>   It runs programs and watches output.
>   When output matches a given pattern
>   Pexpect can respond as if a human were
>   typing responses."

Comment: Thanks. I will look into Pexpect too.

Answer (score 2):

Use the [`subprocess` module](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html).  Example:

```
import subprocess

# Open the subprocess
proc = subprocess.open('device_console', stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout.subprocess.PIPE)

# Write a command
proc.stdin.write('list\n')

# Read the results back -- this will block until a line of input is received
listing = proc.stdout.readline()

# When you're done, close the input stream so the subprocess knows to exit
proc.stdin.close()

# Wait for subprocess to exit (optional) and get its exit status
exit_status = proc.wait()
```