# Capture subprocess output

Tags: python, subprocess

I learned that when executing commands in Python, I should use subprocess.
What I'm trying to achieve is to encode a file via ffmpeg and observe the program output until the file is done. Ffmpeg logs the progress to stderr.

If I try something like this:

```
child = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
complete = False
while not complete:
    stderr = child.communicate()

    # Get progress
    print "Progress here later"
    if child.poll() is not None:
        complete = True
    time.sleep(2)
```

the programm does not continue after calling child.communicate() and waits for the command to complete. Is there any other way to follow the output?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

communicate() blocks until the child process returns, so the rest of the lines in your loop will only get executed *after* the child process has finished running. Reading from stderr will block too, unless you read character by character like so:

```
import subprocess
import sys
child = subprocess.Popen(command, shell=True, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
while True:
    out = child.stderr.read(1)
    if out == '' and child.poll() != None:
        break
    if out != '':
        sys.stdout.write(out)
        sys.stdout.flush()
```

This will provide you with real-time output. Taken from Nadia's answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1388807/197011).

Comment: you don't need `child.poll()` here; you could [call `child.wait()` at the end instead](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17698359/4279)

Comment: As a pedant, *!= None* is better written *is not None*

Answer (score 1):

[`.communicate()`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate) "Read data from stdout and stderr, until end-of-file is reached. Wait for process to terminate."

Instead, you should be able to just read from `child.stderr` like an ordinary file.