# wxPython Subprocess communication : Extracting real time output and updating in the Text Control

Tags: wxpython

This is my post and hence please do not mind of any mistakes ,
what i wanted the help is about extracting/displaying the real output and 
updating the values in my text control area. For example : if i have to update 
the signal catch by a device and have to update in my GUI text Control area and 
the code that extracts the signal  data is define in other module.Please do guide in
getting and updating my text control area in real time fashion.
Hope my post is not confusing and understandable.
I referred [Capture subprocess output](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2525263/capture-subprocess-output)
but this is not working in mine.

Thanx in advance.

Anil ph

Answer (score 0):

I would try using [threads](http://docs.python.org/library/threading.html).  The Gui will be the main thread, and you can have another thread that catches the device output.  You will then need to communicate information from the catching thread to the Gui thread, and [queues](http://docs.python.org/library/queue.html) are generally a good way of doing that.