# How to capture the output from "subprocess.call" to a file?

Tags: python, subprocess

In my code I have a line similar to this:

```
rval = subprocess.call(["mkdir",directoryName], shell=True)
```

and I can check `rval` to see if it is `0` or `1`, but if it is `1`, I would like to have the text from the command `"A subdirectory or file ben already exists."` in a file format, so I can compare it to another file if I want to make sure the text is the same.

Is it possible to have a line like this, but I know this does not work

```
rval = subprocess.call(["mkdir",directoryName], shell=True) >> filename
```

so no matter what happens with the command, the text is captured in `filename`, and `rval` still has the return code?

Comment: Duplicate of all of these:  http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bpython%5D+subprocess+capture

Comment: possible duplicate of [Capture subprocess output](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2525263/capture-subprocess-output)

Comment: why are you not using Python's builtin `mkdir()` ?

Comment: I am doing this for a command I can not post here, but it has similar characteristics as mkdir.

Comment: @S.Lott, it's *almost* a duplicate. The difference would be `Popen` vs `call` (which I agree is subtle), and the desire to write to a file rather than capturing the output within the program. Even though it seems the questioner would rather capture the output, it's useful to answer the question as-is.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

```
import subprocess
f = open(r'c:\temp\temp.txt','w')
subprocess.call(['dir', r'c:\temp'], shell=True, stdout=f)
f.close()
```

Comment: Any reason why you used 'shell=True' in this case? Cause I read using that is a bad idea (on *nix at least).

Comment: @PulpFiction, two reasons: first it was included in the original question, second I was using a Windows shell command for testing.

Answer (score 17):

The subprocess module has a built in 'check_output' function for doing this:

```
In [11]: result = subprocess.check_output(['pwd'])

In [12]: print result
/home/vagrant
```

Comment: But then you lose the exit value :(

Comment: Note that check_output is only possible since 2.7

Answer (score 12):

```
import subprocess

try:
    result = subprocess.check_output(['dir', r'c:\temp'], shell=True)
    print result
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    return_code = e.returncode
```

You anyway need to use try catch because it throws exception if return code is non zero :)

Comment: It would be simpler to just use `except CalledProcessError as e: returncode=e.returncode`.