# How to grab the output from python subprocess

Tags: python, linux, subprocess, wget

I am executing the python script from commandline with this

`python myscript.py`

This is my script

```
if item['image_urls']:
            for image_url in item['image_urls']:
            subprocess.call(['wget','-nH', image_url, '-P  images/'])
```

Now when i run that the on the screen i see output like this

```
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: 4159 (4.1K) [image/png]
```

now what i want is that there should be no ouput on the terminal.

i want to grab the ouput and find the image extension from there i.e from `[image/png]` grab the `png` and renaqme the file to `something.png`

Is this possible

Comment: check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3979888/in-python-scipting-how-do-i-capture-output-from-subprocess-call-to-a-file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If all you want is to download something using `wget`, why not try [urllib.urlretrieve](http://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html#urllib.urlretrieve) in standard python library?

```
import os
import urllib
image_url = "https://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo3w.png"
image_filename = os.path.basename(image_url)
urllib.urlretrieve(image_url, image_filename)
```

**EDIT**: If the images are dynamically redirected by a script, you may try [`requests`](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/v0.10.7/user/quickstart/#redirection-and-history) package to handle the redirection.

```
import requests
r = requests.get(image_url)
# here r.url will return the redirected true image url
image_filename = os.path.basename(r.url)
f = open(image_filename, 'wb')
f.write(r.content)
f.close()
```

I haven't test the code since I do not find a suitable test case. One big advantage for `requests` is it can also handle [authorization](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/v0.10.7/user/quickstart/#basic-authentication).

**EDIT2**: If the image is dynamically served by a script, like [gravatar](http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/92fb4563ddc5ceeaa8b19b60a7a172f4) image, you can usually find the filename in the response header's `content-disposition` field.

```
import urllib2
url = "http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/92fb4563ddc5ceeaa8b19b60a7a172f4"
req = urllib2.Request(url)
r = urllib2.urlopen(req)
# you can check the returned header and find where the filename is loacated
print r.headers.dict
s = r.headers.getheader('content-disposition')
# just parse the filename
filename = s[s.index('"')+1:s.rindex('"')]
f = open(filename, 'wb')
f.write(r.read())
f.close()
```

**EDIT3**: As @Alex suggested in the comment, you may need to sanitize the encoded `filename` in the returned header, I think just get the basename is ok.

```
import os
# this will remove the dir path in the filename
# so that `../../../etc/passwd` will become `passwd`
filename = os.path.basename(filename)
```

Comment: My Image url is something like this `image.php?u=155594&dateline=1182409179` and i don't know what will be its extension. can i find that with urllib

Comment: Is the url is a redirection to the real image url? pls check my updated answer.

Comment: I get this error `import: unable to open X server `. i dont know there is url redirection or not but i open that link in browser then incan see the image there like `http://www.example.com/image.php?u=155594&dateline=1182409179` shows the image in browser without any chnage in url

Comment: Make sure that `filename` isn't malicious - use something like [`secure_filename()`](http://werkzeug.pocoo.org/docs/utils/#werkzeug.utils.secure_filename) to prevent `../../../etc/passwd`