# is there a way to run 1 module on an older python version

Tags: python, python-2.7

We are developing a tool and use various third party modules. Currently everything is running on python 2.5 but this causes a lot of problems. We would like to update to python 2.7, but 1 (One) module is 2.5 only. Is there a good way to run 1 package on a different python version. The only way we can think of is with threads, but maybe there is something simpler?

Comment: Most modules written for 2.5 can run just fine on Python 2.7. If the module does not work on 2.7, there is no way for you to somehow run it on an older version, not without extensive inter-process message passing, anyway.

Comment: Not this one though. We tried, but it didn't work. Also there is no support to get it running on 2.7.

Comment: Then you are out of luck, unless you write some kind of daemon in Python 2.5 to run the module then pass messages between processes.

Comment: See e.g. http://stackoverflow.com/q/17665124/3001761

Comment: If you have the source code for the library, upgrade it to run on Python 2.7.

Comment: What errors do you get if you run the module on 2.5 ?

Comment: Why can't you just contribute a patch for this third-party module?

Comment: We don't gave the source. The error I get is "bad magic number", complete in line with trying to run a compiled file in the wrong version of Python.

Comment: @TomM. What exactly *is* this third-party package? What does it do? Have you looked for alternatives?