# Launching python3 script using a python2 script

Tags: python, python-3.x

is there a way to launch a script running on python3 via a python2 script.

To explain briefly I need to start the python3 script when starting the python2 script.

Python3 script is a video stream server (using Flask) and have to run simultaneously from the python2 script (not python3 script first and then python2 script).

The ideal would be to get a function in the python2 script which "open a cmd window and write" it in : python3 script_python3.py

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. create command in bash file. command is to run script_python3.py, ex: python script_python3.py
2. then from python2 file, run the .bash file. ex:
   import os
   os.popen('sh /scripts/my_bash.sh')

Comment: ok i try this and tell you

Comment: I used this finally (near to yours):

#!/usr/bin/env python2
from subprocess import Popen

Popen('path/to/script_python3.py')

Comment: great to hear :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31756908/5621318).

That use case of that question is a bit different, but the answer should work.