# Simple unit test in Python to check input and expected output

Tags: python, unit-testing

I have this simple program in Python (`hello.py`):

```
name=input()
print("Hello " + name)
```

As simple as that, no classes, no functions, no nothing, just an input and the corresponding output.

My aim is just to create `test_hello.py`, a test file for `hello.py`. I spend a few hours searching on the internet, but I only found unit tests for functions or methods but not for a simple input and output program. Any clue? Thank you a lot in advance!

Note: Stack overflow suggests that there is an answer: [How to assert output with nosetest/unittest in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4219717/how-to-assert-output-with-nosetest-unittest-in-python)
But the two questions are very different, there aren't functions in my code and there is an `input()`. In the "answer" suggested the code is inside a function and there is no `input()`.

Comment: Is there a specific reason? and how would you check the expected output? It should, for example, return something or write the output to the file.

Comment: Might be better to write a bash script for this

Comment: I just don't see how you are going to import or call this to run in your test as it is not function, you would have to code `hello.py` to run in the test code, v a predicted outcome which you could do with a function, but you don't want to use functions, hmm

Answer (score 1):

Finally, I came up with the solution:

```
import unittest
import os
import subprocess

class TestHello(unittest.TestCase):

    def test_case1(self):
        input = "Alan"
        expected_output = "Hello Alan"
        with os.popen("echo '" + input + "' | python hello.py") as o:
            output = o.read()
        output = output.strip() # Remove leading spaces and LFs
        self.assertEqual(output, expected_output)

    def test_case2(self):
        input = "John"
        expected_output = "Hello John"
        with os.popen("echo '" + input + "' | python hello.py") as o:
            output = o.read()
        output = output.strip() # Remove leading spaces and LFs
        self.assertEqual(output, expected_output)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    unittest.main()
```

I have two test cases: "Alan" must print "Hello Alan" and John must print "Hello John".

Thanks guys for your clues!

Answer (score 0):

I really suggest using classes or functions, but if you insisted then you can try to use it in a subprocess and capture the output

[this might help](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2525263/capture-subprocess-output)

Comment: Thank you for your answer. Yes, I insisted. How can I use it in a subprocess and capture the output?

Comment: This link might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2525263/capture-subprocess-output

Comment: This one is probably better https://www.endpoint.com/blog/2015/01/28/getting-realtime-output-using-python