# Calling multiple commands using os.system in Python

Tags: python, unix, subprocess, command

I would like to invoke multiple commands from my python script.
I tried using the os.system(), however, I'm running into issues when the current directory is changed.

example:

```
os.system("ls -l")
os.system("<some command>") # This will change the present working directory 
os.system("launchMyApp") # Some application invocation I need to do.
```

Now, the third call to launch doesn't work.

Answer (score 34):

[`os.system`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.html#os.system) is a wrapper for the C standard library function [`system()`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/system.html). Its argument can be any valid [shell command](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09) as long as it fits into the memory reserved for environment and argument lists of a process.

So, delimit each command with a semicolon or a newline and they will be executed one after another in the same environment.

```
os.system(" ls -l; <some command>; launchMyApp")
```

```
os.system('''
ls -l
<some command>
launchMyApp
''')
```

Answer (score 9):

Try this

```
import os

os.system("ls -l")
os.chdir('path') # This will change the present working directory
os.system("launchMyApp") # Some application invocation I need to do.
```

Answer (score 3):

Each process has its own current working directory. Normally, child processes can't change parent's directory that is why `cd` is a builtin shell command: it runs in the same (shell) process.

Each `os.system()` call creates a new shell process. Changing the directory inside these processes has no effect on the parent python process and therefore on the subsequent shell processes.

To run multiple commands in the same shell instance, you could use `subprocess` module:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from subprocess import check_call

check_call(r"""set -e
ls -l
<some command> # This will change the present working directory 
launchMyApp""", shell=True)
```

If you know the destination directory; [use `cwd` parameter suggested by @Puffin GDI instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20042319/4279).

Answer (score 3):

It’s simple, really.
For Windows separate your commands with `&`, for Linux, separate them with `;`.
`str.replace` is a very good way to approach the problem, used in the example below:

```
import os
os.system('''cd /
mkdir somedir'''.replace('\n', ';')) # or use & for Windows
```

Answer (score 1):

When you call *os.system()*, every time you create a subshell - that closes immediately when *os.system* returns (*subprocess* is the recommended library to invoke OS commands). If you need to invoke a set of commands - invoke them in one call. 
BTW, you may change working director from Python - *os.chdir*

Comment: Could you please share an example using subprocess?

Answer (score 1):

Try to use [subprocess.Popen](http://docs.python.org/2/library/subprocess.html#popen-constructor) and `cwd`

example:

```
subprocess.Popen('launchMyApp', cwd=r'/working_directory/')
```

Comment: I may not know the changed directory. Is there a way I could get the changed directory from the previous call ? so that I could pass that while calling to "launchMyApp"

Comment: If you need to get output from cmd. Maybe you can refer (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388753/how-to-get-output-from-subprocess-popen)

Comment: `p = subprocess.Popen( ...) ` and `line = p.stdout.readline()`

Answer (score -1):

You can change back to the directory you need to be in with `os.chdir()`

Answer (score -1):

Just use

```
// it will execute all commands even if anyone in betweeen fails
os.system("first command;second command;third command")
// or, it will try to execite but will stop as any command fails
os.system("first command && second command && third command")
```

I think you have got the idea what to do

> Note: This is not a very reliable approach if you are doing a complex
> job using CLI tools. Popen and subprocess methods are better there.
> Although small task link copy, move, list will work fine

.

Answer (score -1):

`os.system("ls -l && <some command>")`