# How to execute multiple commands in powershell using python?

Tags: python, powershell

I have the following code:

```
import os

os.system(cd new_folder)
```

Now, this code changes the directory to the "new_folder" folder, but what I want to do is make the directory stay in that state so I can conduct another line of code, such as the following:

```
import os

os.system(cd new_folder)
os.system(md good_folder)
```

What I intend to do in the above is after I move inside the "new_folder" folder directory, I make another folder named "good_folder" inside the "new_folder" folder.

But I can't seem to find a way to make the directory stay in the same place... how can this be done?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have multiple commands separated by semicolons. In your case it would look like:

```
import os

os.system("cd someFolder; mkdir newFolder")
```

Refer to this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20042205/calling-multiple-commands-using-os-system-in-python) for further explanation.