# How can Python 3.9 be used to permanently modify a Linux user's $PATH?

Tags: python-3.x, debian

Distro:  Debian 11
Python:  3.9.2
Shell:   Bash
I'm attempting to permanently update a user's path using Python.  I want to essentially do the equivalent of this using Python:

```
export PATH="$PATH:/usr/local/bin/folderA"  
export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.local/share/folderB/bin"  
echo export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin" >> "$HOME"/.bashrc
```

In Python I attempted:

```
import os  
from pathlib import Path  

dir_home = str(Path.home())  

os.system('export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/folderA')
os.system('export PATH=$PATH:' + dir_home + '/.local/share/folderB/bin')
os.system('echo export PATH=$PATH:' + dir_home + '/.local/bin >>' + dir_home + '/.bashrc')
```

The `echo export PATH="$PATH:$HOME/.local/bin" >> "$HOME"/.bashrc` works but the other two lines don't get input into the $PATH.

I don't care how it gets done though.  I am using this method as I thought it was the way to do it.

Thanks

Comment: You cannot modify one process' environment from a subprocess.

Comment: That info really helped.  Wasn't thinking.  I will attempt to run all the commands in one os.system call and see if that works.  Like this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20042205/calling-multiple-commands-using-os-system-in-python  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Run all the commands at once with one `os.system` call.

```
#################################################################################
import os
from pathlib import Path

dir_home = str(Path.home())

p1 = 'export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/folderA; '
p2 = 'export PATH=$PATH:' + dir_home + '/.local/share/folderB/bin; '
p3 = 'echo export PATH=$PATH:' + dir_home + '/.local/bin >>' + dir_home + '/.bashrc'

os.system(p1 + p2 + p3)
#################################################################################
```

Comment: How can this possibly work? As noted in comments a subprocess can't change the environment of the parent, and `os.system` will make a subprocess. The final line will work to make a change to your .bashrc though.

Comment: I don't know anything, but it worked on my system.