# Running dd from python and getting progress

Tags: python, pipe, popen, dd

this is my code but it doesn't works.
dd command is executed, but no output is printed out.
Note: if I change the stdout to a regular text file, the dd output is progressively saved in the file at every progress line that dd prints out.

Ideas?
Regards.

```
import sys
from subprocess import Popen, STDOUT, PIPE

with Popen(["dd", "if=/dev/cdrom", "of=/tmp/prova.iso", "bs=2048", "count=499472", "status=progress"], stderr=STDOUT, stdout=PIPE) as proc:
    print("ok")
    print(proc.stdout.read())
```

Comment: I'll leave you with [this](https://gist.github.com/Torxed/581a6cda6d6b97541509f3ca258af042) which shows how you can print data when it's available at each line break/carriage return. Giving a answer to this question would be pretty broad and there's already topics on SO about this particular matter.

Comment: There's also this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388753/how-to-get-output-from-subprocess-popen-proc-stdout-readline-blocks-no-dat

Comment: Thanks @Torxed, I've get the cmd.py. I thought that, by running cmd.py in a shell, I could see printed the result of "ls -l", which seems to be the command that is launched by default. However, when I launch cmd.py, nothing happens. What is wrong?

Comment: Thank you @Steve. I've found a solution with this link.

Answer (score 2):

I've found a solution.

```
import subprocess
import sys

cmd = ["dd", "if=/dev/cdrom", "of=/tmp/iso.iso", "bs=2048", "count=499472", "status=progress"]

process = subprocess.Popen(cmd, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)

line = ''
while True:
    out = process.stderr.read(1)
    if out == '' and process.poll() != None:
        break
    if out != '':
        s = out.decode("utf-8")
        if s == '\r':
            print(line)
            line = ''
        else:
            line = line + s
```

Thank you all for your answers.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at this:
[dd with progress in python](https://gist.github.com/hikoz/741643)