# Running a shell script using Subprocess in Python does not produce output

Tags: python, windows, shell, subprocess, sh

I am trying to run a shell script using through Python using subprocess.Popen().

The shell script just has the following lines:

```
#!/bin/sh
echo Hello World
```

Following is the Python code:

```
print("RUNNNING SHELL SCRIPT NOW")
shellscript = subprocess.Popen(['km/example/example1/source/test.sh'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)
shellscript.wait()

for line in shellscript.stdout.readlines():
    print(line)
print("SHELL SCRIPT RUN ENDED")
```

However, on running this, I am only getting the following output:

```
RUNNNING SHELL SCRIPT NOW
SHELL SCRIPT RUN ENDED
```

i.e. I am not getting the shell script output in between these 2 lines.

Moreover, when I remove the `stderr=subprocess.PIPE` part from the subprocess, I get the following output:

```
RUNNNING SHELL SCRIPT NOW
'km' is not defined as an internal or external command.
SHELL SCRIPT RUN ENDED
```

I am not able to understand how to resolve this, and run the shell script properly. Kindly guide. Thanks.

UPDATE:

I also tried the following change:

```
print("RUNNNING SHELL SCRIPT NOW")
shellscript = subprocess.Popen(['km/example/example1/source/test.sh'], stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, shell=True)

out, err = shellscript.communicate()
print(out)
print("SHELL SCRIPT RUN ENDED")
```

I get the following output:

```
RUNNNING SHELL SCRIPT NOW
b''
SHELL SCRIPT RUN ENDED
```

Comment: maybe
[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1388753/how-to-get-output-from-subprocess-popen-proc-stdout-readline-blocks-no-dat)
and [that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2502833/store-output-of-subprocess-popen-call-in-a-string) will help you

Comment: Usually the first to do when using subprocess, is to check if `shellscript.returncode == 0` otherwise there as was an error (details should be available in `err`). The command passed to `Popen` has to be a string when using `shell=True`, whereas `shell=False` requires the command as `list`

Comment: You are using a relative path (not starting with `/`). Nothing wrong with that *provided you make sure what the current working directory is*. When using an IDE it is often not what you would expect. (Just add `import os` and `print(os.getcwd)` to control it...)

Comment: use shell=True and pass the command as string not list and one more thing your path is not correct provide absolute path to the script from very begining e.g. /var/www/file.html

Comment: @ZainUlAbidin That is _precisely_ incorrect advice. You want to avoid `shell=True` when you can.

Comment: @tripleee Yes i know but i don't think so for now he even care about security he just wants his code to be executed and show some output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple and straightforward fix is to not use bare `Popen` for this.

You also don't need a shell to run a subprocess; if the subprocess is a shell script, that subprocess itself will be a shell, but you don't need the help of the shell to *run* that script.

```py
proc = subprocess.run(
    ['km/example/example1/source/test.sh'],
    check=True, capture_output=True, text=True)
out = proc.stdout
```

If you really need to use `Popen`, you need to understand its processing model. But if you are just trying to get the job done, the simple answer is don't use `Popen`.

The error message actually looks like you are on Windows, and it tries to run `km` via `cmd` which thinks the slashes are option separators, not directory separators. Removing the `shell=True` avoids this complication, and just starts a process with the requested name. (This of course still requires that the file exists in the relative file name you are specifying. Perhaps see also [What exactly is current working directory?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45591428/what-exactly-is-current-working-directory) and also perhaps switch to native Windows backslashes, with an `r'...'` string to prevent Python from trying to interpret the backslashes.)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. Yes I don't really need to use Popen. Yes, I am on Windows.
When I run your code snippet, I get 
`
OSError: [WinError 193] %1 is not a valid Win32 application
`
What could this be related to?

Comment: If `km/example/example1/source/test.sh` is not a valid Windows application, that would be the explanation. I don't know how you would expect shell scripts to work on Cygwin; maybe explicitly run it with `['/bin/sh', 'km/example/example1/source/test.sh']`?

Comment: I had to provide the complete path starting from the Drive. However, when the script runs, a terminal window open for just a second displays the output and closes itself. Is there a way to display the output on the Pycharm terminal instead, so that it stays there?

Comment: No experience with PyCharm and very little of Python on Windows; but this sounds like a common FAQ. Ask a new question if you can't find it already answered.