# Python subprocess.Popen stdin interfering with stdout/stderr

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

Very puzzled by this. When using Popen, if only using stdout or stderr the following code works:

```
def run(self):
    self.externalProcess = subprocess.Popen(['./external_process.out 1>&2'], shell=True, stderr=subprocess.PIPE)
    while self.externalBinary.poll() is None:
        print('Still running')
    print('Done running')
```

I'm using the stderr file descriptor because I'm monitoring the process output real time in a GUI and stderr is unbuffered. See my other question for more background on that mess:
[Python capture stdout from subprocess line by line](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7608883/943814)

The problem I'm having here is that as soon as I add stdin to allow user input to be passed to the external process it starts acting as though stdout is buffered again:

```
def run(self):
    self.externalProcess = subprocess.Popen(['./external_process.out 1>&2'], shell=True, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, stdin=subprocess.PIPE)
    while self.externalBinary.poll() is None:
        print('Still running')
    print('Done running')
```

My question is why does stdin appear to be affecting stdout and stderr?

Comment: What exactly are the symptoms of your problem? Something blocked that shouldn't be?

Comment: Also, working code would be appreciated - your examples do not run as written. What is `stdout=STDERR`, for example?

Comment: Yeah I noticed that there is no such thing as subprocess.STDERR. Should be fixed now. The symptoms are that I have a textbox in my wxPython app that displays the output a line at a time. When I add the stdin argument it only displays a few lines that stops. When I remove it it continues displaying the output from my external process, which is a C program.

Comment: Where do you actually send input to the child process? I don't see that happening in your second example...

Comment: I didn't include it because I see the issue as soon as I add the argument. I don't even need to try using stdin. After reading the link below I think my problem is that I'm deadlocking due to caching, so I'm working on getting around that. I don't need to use stdin until I close down the child process (I'm just sending a newline to simulate the enter key being pressed which is how that program exits cleanly).

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you might be trying to write data to the subprocess (via STDIN) as well as read its output (via STDOUT) interactively.

As mentioned in the answer to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1277866/python-subprocess-module-looping-over-stdout-of-child-process), that is a no-no!

You could use [`Popen.communicate`](http://docs.python.org/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.Popen.communicate), but that is a blocking call which will wait for all communication to finish (you can't poll as you do in your example)

Comment: Good link. I didn't understand the deadlocking issue before. I'm trying to get communicate working but it's not so far. See my comment above.

Comment: @tanders12: What problems are you having with `communicate()` ?

Comment: communicate() appears to buffer everything until the child exits. I need it line buffered or unbuffered. I'm trying to accomplish this without changing the code in the child. Right now I'm attempting to make pexpect work and it looks promising.